# Which is more preferable in terms of performance Javascript and jQuery or PHP given same type of work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance

**Description :**

I have couple of functions that can be written in JavaScript and PHP aswell.

e.g

(a) Current datetime calculation and their subtraction

(b) String replace , extracting substring , checking for a position of character in string and many more

I can submit the data in two ways either I can perform all the calculations and functions on client side using JavaScript

**OR**

I can send all the raw data to php and do the exact same work in PHP there before saving it in the database.

**My Question :**

What should I focus on more and try to write as much as I can in either of the languages ?

Comment: When you can, always do as much work on the server as possible.  Clients may not support some features, or have JS off, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is what you're after, do as much as you can in javascript, because client's computer tends to have more free computing power than your server. That is because a client only has to do it for himself, server would need to do it for all visitors - possibly thousands upon thousands. Expected client base is a major factor here.

However, take into consideration that a client can't be "trusted"; if you're going to insert something in database, verify everything that needs to be right.

If supporting visitors without javascript is something you'd care to do, you obviously have to move everything server side, but that is rarely the case nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

If anything that you are trying to do is for validation, then do it on the server side with PHP.  The client side is ***untrustworthy and unreliable*** for that sort of thing.

As far as efficiency goes, in terms of calculations/processing power, your server is likely going to be beefier than the client.  You may have a client with a beast of a machine, but gnerally speaking your server's hardware out perform the client hardware.  Better to keep as much of your processing you can on the server.

Comment: the client side being untrustworthy is absolutely right but I doubt that putting load on the server is a good idea ... see before the server starts to perform actions on my code the script needs to be uploaded first then the functions will start working so yes ! the validation should be done in php but all the other work should be done in javascript.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto Many factors are at play.  Script upload means nothing, you do that once.  Validation aside, the big question is, what can be done in Javascript that isn't important?  How would you respond to a user that has diabled JS?  If something is needed that is done with JS and is unavailable, then you have alienated that user. (I will concede though that users with JS disabled are the exception and not the norm.) Your question was about efficiency. Web servers are optimized to deliver content.  Clients have all sorts of things that can bog down the browser...including JS.